# How to search the contents which created in Xcode 's Images.xcassets?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageasset

For a example , i created a color set in Images.xcassets , and i want to find all the reference  to this color (include code and xib etc) , but the Xcode 's search function seems can't do this kind of work , Can i get all the refrences to  the contents in Images.xcassets?

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems no better solution than a shell command like this (where the L_F3F3F3_D_000000 is the color set name in xcassets file)

```
grep -i -r  "L_F3F3F3_D_000000" ./
```